# Active admin dashboard not listing database row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, psql

I have a rails app that is using active admin. In the dashboard I have all my tables listed and they all work fine except for one.

http://prntscr.com/k0mjzu

This one doesn't display anything like the table is empty, but you can see it says displaying all 2 Ads, but they don't show up.

The only thing I can think of is my `routes.rb` for Ads has a `path: :poster` but even if I remove it, nothing changes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :ads
  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)


resources :ads, path: :poster do
  collection do
    post 'getAds'
  end
  member do
    put 'update_status'
  end
end
```

this is my `admin/ad.rb`

```
 ActiveAdmin.register Ad do

 permit_params :client_id, :ad_size_id, :status, :note

 index do
  selectable_column
   id_column
   column :client_id
   column :ad_size_id
   column :status
   column :note
   actions
 end

 filter :client_id
 filter :ad_size_id
 filter :status
 filter :note

 form do |f|
   f.inputs "User Details" do
     f.input :client_id
     f.input :ad_size_id
     f.input :status
     f.input :note
   end
   f.actions
 end
 end
```

this is `models/ad.rb`

```
 class Ad < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :client
   belongs_to :ad_size

   validates :ad_size, presence: true
 end
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What does `admin/ads.rb` or `admin/ad.rb` look like?

Comment: @JoshBrody I just edited the post

Comment: What does `app/models/ad.rb` look like?

Comment: @JoshBrody thanks for the help, I just added my `models/ab.rb`

Comment: Are you able to make a reproducible example and/or put this on Github somewhere? There's no reason why what you posted shouldn't work.

Comment: @JoshBrody Unfortunately I can't right now, I may be able to some time tomorrow, but I was playing around with my seed file, and it displays the ads perfectly fine after id 10, not sure why.  http://prntscr.com/k0njdu it still says displaying all 15 ads but only shows them after Id 10.

Comment: try removing `selectable_column` and `id_column`

Comment: @emaillenin Tried it, still only showing ads after id 10

Comment: Hey @Matt, were you able to solve it? I have the same problem on 1 computer, but on another, it seems to work fine - so weird!

Answer (score 1):

Bumped into this one today as well. If nothing else helps, you can always try to disable AdBlock. It solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your ads table is missing a primary key. Are any exceptions reported in your development.log?